# Passing empty list as parameter to JPA query throws error

Tags: java, hibernate, list, jpa, persistence

If I pass an empty list into a JPA query, I get an error.

For example:

```
List<Municipality> municipalities = myDao.findAll();  // returns empty list
em.createQuery("SELECT p FROM Profile p JOIN p.municipality m WHERE m IN (:municipalities)")
    .setParameter("municipalities", municipalities)
    .getResultList();
```

Because the list is empty, Hibernate generates this in SQL as "IN ()", which gives me error with Hypersonic database.

There is a ticket for this in [Hibernate issue tracking](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-2045) but there are not many comments/activity there. I don't know about support in other ORM products or in JPA spec either.

I don't like the idea of having to manually check for null objects and empty lists every time. Is there some commonly known approach/extension to this? How do you handle these situations?

Comment: ""IN ()", which gives me error with Hypersonic database."  This happens with MySQL as well.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

According to the section **4.6.8 In Expressions** from the JPA 1.0 specification:

> There must be at least one element in the comma separated list that defines the set of values for the `IN` expression.

In other words, regardless of Hibernate's ability to parse the query and to pass an `IN()`, regardless of the support of this syntax by particular databases (PosgreSQL doesn't according to the Jira issue), you should use a dynamic query here if you want your code to be portable (and I usually prefer to use the Criteria API for dynamic queries).

Comment: I'm currently using JPA 1.0 which doesn't have the criteria API. I was going to upgrade to JPA 2.0 but Hibernate 3.5 is not yet final so that's not option. However, with criteria API one still has to manually avoid nulls and empty lists, it's just easier to do so. Please correct me if I'm wrong. JPA 1.0 having been some time around, I'm sure people have come up with solutions to handle dynamic queries with JPA 1.0 spec?

Comment: @Tuukka 1) You're right, no Criteria API in JPA 1.0 2) Indeed, the Criteria API just makes handling nulls easier/cleaner but you still have to handle them 3) AFAIK, the solution is to build the JPQL query string dynamically at runtime.

Comment: @Tuukka Note that in your particular case, you should just use two different static queries.

Comment: Using *Spring Data*: instead of passing an empty list, pass `null`. it will evaluate as false.

Comment: @TecHunter, no, it'll throw java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Value must not be null! if you try to input null

Comment: @Max with Spring Data? how do you pass it? make another SO question

Comment: @TecHunter `null` does not work as expected in `NOT IN` queries.

Answer (score 21):

Assuming the SQL query to be like

```
(COALESCE(:placeHolderName,NULL) IS NULL OR Column_Name in (:placeHolderName))
```

Now, If the List is of type String then you can pass as

```
query.setParameterList("placeHolderName", 
!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(list)? list : new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("")).
```

And If the List is containing the Integer values then the syntax is like below:

```
If(!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(list)){
query.setParameterList("placeHolderName",list)
}else{
query.setParameter("placeHolderName",null, Hibernate.INTEGER)
}
```

Comment: you can just write `COALESCE(:placeHolderName)` instead of `COALESCE(:placeHolderName,NULL)`

Comment: For the integer list you can also do this: AND ar.productid = ANY(COALESCE(:productIds, ARRAY[ar.productid])) it will work just fine.

Answer (score 13):

I struggled with this issue, too. I found out that the Hibernate community has RESOLVED the issue in **Hibernate version 5.4.10**, here is the ticket: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8091

You can check your Hibernate version `System.out.println(org.hibernate.Version.getVersionString());`

And you can UPDATE the version of Hibernate to the latest, here is a useful link: https://hibernate.org/orm/releases/

Answer (score 7):

I ran into the same problem today and [@r_divyas's response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55315864/9128896) almost did it for me, but there was a small change I had to do in order to make it work.

I have a query that I save in the database so I couldn't change it on the fly. This query triggers the build of a dynamic UI according to the fields in the result set.

In the UI I have a multiple choice dropdown, which is optional. So there can be 0, 1 or more elements selected from it.

Therefore, I needed to find a way to make this parameter optional in my query.
Initially, I set it up as:

`(:assignedUsers IS NULL OR wr.USR_ID IN (:assignedUsers))`

Unfortunately, this worked with only a null parameter or a list of a single element. At the point of design, I didn't test it with multiple elements in the list. When I finally got there, I encountered the following error:

`SQL Error [4145] [S0001]: An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ','.`

Which was caused by the following code:

`AND (('id1', 'id2', 'id3') IS NULL OR wr.USR_ID IN ('id1', 'id2', 'id3'))`

I then tried his solution, which was indeed working when my list was not null or empty. But when it was, the query was becoming this:

`AND (COALESCE('', NULL) IS NULL OR wr.USR_ID IN (''))`

Which was causing the result set to be empty.

And now, proceeding to the solution I found. All I had to do was to change the condition in the query:

`AND (COALESCE(:assignedUsers, NULL) = '' OR wr.USR_ID IN (:assignedUsers))`

And this is working for an empty list, a null value, a list with a single or more elements.

Comment: wow suberb answer

Comment: This also works: AND ar.productid = ANY(COALESCE(:productIds, ARRAY[ar.productid]))

Answer (score 4):

Solution:

```
if (municipalities==null || municipalities.isEmpty())
    .setParameter("municipalities", "''")
else
    .setParameter("municipalities", municipalities)
```

Comment: In my question: _I don't like the idea of having to manually check for null objects and empty lists every time_.

Comment: in your case if you work because you will you send the list, if a query that yields the same query these index specified was not found results

Comment: " ' ' " is not dependable, the type you are checking for is, say Long, then it fails with ``value [''] did not match expected type [java.lang.Long``. Anyway if you are adding check in java, then return empty list instead of firing a query.

Answer (score 4):

My simple solution was to add an aux parameter to flag the condition like in the below example:

```sql
where (:doNotCheckList = 1)
   or (fieldName in :valuesList)
```

```java
query
  .setParameter("doNotCheckList", (!valuesList.isEmpty() ? 1 : 0))
  .setParameter("valuesList",     valuesList);
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you're querying DB sequence IDs that typically start at 1, you can add 0 to the list

```
if (excludeIds.isEmpty()) {
    excludeIds.add(new Long("0"));
}
List<SomeEntity> retval = someEntityRepo.findByIdNotIn(excludeIds);
```

Maybe -1 works too.  Small work around for the use of jpa repos.

Answer (score 1):

After having no actual solution as replies, I created a proxy class to handle these situations. The idea is to retain native syntax where possible.

**WARNING:** This is work-in-progress and very hazardous approach. The code below is by no mean meant as complete solution and quite possibly contains zillions of bugs and scary cases.

That being said, the BlankAwareQuery class wraps the javax.persistence Query and is initialized with EntityManager and the core query string (which cannot contain empty lists or lists of enumerations).

```
BlankAwareQuery query = new BlankAwareQuery(em, "SELECT p FROM Profile p");
```

After creation of class, dynamic parts are inserted with

```
query.from("p.address a");
query.where("a IN (:addresses)");
```

Parameters are inserted as always:

```
query.setParameter("addresses", addresses);
```

The point here is that the class removes these (their from-part as well) from query if they are empty lists or manipulates them if they are lists of enumerations.

Then call:

```
query.getResultList();
```

So, for example:

```
List<Profile> profiles = new BlankAwareQuery(em, "SELECT p FROM Profile p")
    .from("p.address a JOIN a.municipality m").where("m IN (:municipalities)")
    .where("p.gender IN (:genders)")
    .where("p.yearOfBirth > :minYear")
    .where("p.yearOfBirth < :maxYear")
    .from("p.platforms f").where("f IN (:platforms)")
    .setParameter("municipalities", municipalities)
    .setParameter("genders", genders)
    .setParameter("minYear", minYear)
    .setParameter("maxYear", maxYear)
    .setParameter("platforms", platforms)
    .getResultList();
```

The actual code (code uses Lombok for @Data and @NonNull annotations and Apache commons lang for StringUtils):

```
public class BlankAwareQuery {

    private @Data class Parameter {
        private @NonNull String fieldName;
        private @NonNull Object value;
    }

    private @Data class ClausePair {
        private @NonNull String from;
        private @NonNull String where;
    }

    private EntityManager em;

    private List<String> select = Lists.newArrayList();
    private List<ClausePair> whereFrom = Lists.newArrayList();
    private String from;
    private List<Parameter> parameters = Lists.newArrayList();
    Query query;

    public BlankAwareQuery(EntityManager em, String query) {

        this.em = em;

        /** Select **/
        int selectStart = StringUtils.indexOf(query, "SELECT ") + 7;
        int selectEnd = StringUtils.indexOf(query, " FROM ");
        select(StringUtils.substring(query, selectStart, selectEnd));

        /** From **/
        int fromStart = selectEnd + 6;
        int fromEnd = StringUtils.indexOf(query, " WHERE ");
        if (fromEnd == -1) fromEnd = query.length();
        from(StringUtils.substring(query, fromStart, fromEnd));

        /** Where **/
        String where = "";
        if (StringUtils.contains(query, " WHERE ")) {
            where = StringUtils.substring(query, fromEnd + 7);
        }
        where(where);
    }

    private BlankAwareQuery select(String s) {
        select.add(s);
        return this;
    }

    public BlankAwareQuery from(String s) {
        from = s;
        return this;
    }

    public BlankAwareQuery where(String s) {
        ClausePair p = new ClausePair(from, s);
        whereFrom.add(p);
        from = "";
        return this;
    }

    public BlankAwareQuery setParameter(String fieldName, Object value) {

        /** Non-empty collection -> include **/
        if (value != null && value instanceof List<?> && !((List<?>) value).isEmpty()) {

            /** List of enums -> parse open (JPA doesn't support defining list of enums as in (:blaa) **/
            if (((List<?>) value).get(0) instanceof Enum<?>) {

                List<String> fields = Lists.newArrayList();

                /** Split parameters into individual entries **/
                int i = 0;
                for (Enum<?> g : (List<Enum<?>>) value) {
                    String fieldSingular = StringUtils.substring(fieldName, 0, fieldName.length() - 1) + i;
                    fields.add(":" + fieldSingular);
                    parameters.add(new Parameter(fieldSingular, g));
                    i++;
                }

                /** Split :enums into (:enum1, :enum2, :enum3) strings **/
                for (ClausePair p : whereFrom) {
                    if (p.getWhere().contains(":" + fieldName)) {
                        int start = StringUtils.indexOf(p.getWhere(), ":" + fieldName);
                        int end = StringUtils.indexOfAny(StringUtils.substring(p.getWhere(), start + 1), new char[] {')', ' '});
                        String newWhere = StringUtils.substring(p.getWhere(), 0, start) + StringUtils.join(fields, ", ") + StringUtils.substring(p.getWhere(), end + start + 1);
                        p.setWhere(newWhere);
                    }
                }
            }
            /** Normal type which doesn't require customization, just add it **/ 
            else {
                parameters.add(new Parameter(fieldName, value));
            }
        }

        /** Not to be included -> remove from and where pair from query **/
        else {
            for (Iterator<ClausePair> it = whereFrom.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
                ClausePair p = it.next();
                if (StringUtils.contains(p.getWhere(), fieldName)) {
                    it.remove();
                }
            }
        }

        return this;
    }

    private String buildQueryString() {

        List<String> from = Lists.newArrayList();
        List<String> where = Lists.newArrayList();

        for (ClausePair p : whereFrom) {
            if (!p.getFrom().equals("")) from.add(p.getFrom());
            if (!p.getWhere().equals("")) where.add(p.getWhere());
        }

        String selectQuery = StringUtils.join(select, ", ");
        String fromQuery = StringUtils.join(from, " JOIN ");
        String whereQuery = StringUtils.join(where, " AND ");

        String query = "SELECT " + selectQuery + " FROM " + fromQuery + (whereQuery == "" ? "" : " WHERE " + whereQuery);

        return query;
    }

    public Query getQuery() {
        query = em.createQuery(buildQueryString());
        setParameters();
        return query;
    }

    private void setParameters() {
        for (Parameter par : parameters) {
            query.setParameter(par.getFieldName(), par.getValue());
        }
    }

    public List getResultList() {
        return getQuery().getResultList();
    }

    public Object getSingleResult() {
        return getQuery().getSingleResult();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use two parameters `municipalitiesb` and `municipalities`.
`municipalitiesb` activate or desactivate the IN condition.
In case `municipalities` is empty, I use a dummy `Municipality`.

```
//protection against NPE
if(municipalities == null) municipalities = Collections.emptyList();
em.createQuery("SELECT p FROM Profile p JOIN p.municipality m WHERE (:municipalitiesb IS NULL OR m IN (:municipalities))")
    .setParameter("municipalitiesb", municipalities.isEmpty() ? null : 1)
    .setParameter("municipalities", municipalities.isEmpty() ? Arrays.asList(new Municipality()), municipalities)
    .getResultList();
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are using spring/hibernate annotations then one of the easiest ways of working around this is having two parameters. First lets define our JPA annotation:

```
        + "AND (p.myVarin :state OR :nullCheckMyVar is null) "
```

Then pass those parameters in as normal:

```
    @Param("myVarin") List<Integers> myVarin,
    @Param("nullCheckMyVar") Integer nullCheckMyVar,
```

Finally in what ever service call you can do the following:

```
    Integer nullCheckInteger = null;
    if (myVarIn != null && !myVarIn.isEmpty()) {
        // we can use any integer
        nullCheckInteger = 1;
    }
    repo.callService(myVarIn, nullCheckInteger);
```

And then pass those two parms into the call.

What does this do? If myVarIn is not null and filled then we can specify "all" as 1 != null. Otherwise we pass in our list and null is null and therefore ignored.
This either selects "all" when empty or something when not empty.