# Is it possible to pass and test for an empty list in JPA?

Tags: jpa, jpa-2.0

I have a JPQL named query that takes a `List` as a parameter.  I'm using the parameter in an `IN` phrase:

```
...WHERE x.id IN :list
```

I'd like to do something like the following but the syntax apparently won't let me:

```
...WHERE :list IS EMPTY OR x.id IN :list
```

Neither will:

```
...WHERE SIZE(:list) = 0 OR x.id IN :list
```

Is what I'm trying to do impossible in a JPA 2.0 named query?  I know how to do it via the criteria API or using plain old JPQL strings.

Comment: I believe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55315864/1325216) is the solution to this problem.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

What you are trying to do in the query seems a non sense. You are trying to restrict the query results using the state of a parameter. But you don't compare this parameter with anything in your select.

Think about this query (it make no sense) :

```
SELECT * FROM SOMETABLE WHERE :list IS EMPTY
```

So I think you need to check if the :list is empty before choosing between two different queries:

if `:list` is not empty: `...WHERE x.id IN :list`

if `:list` is empty: `(NO WHERE CLAUSE AT ALL)`

Comment: You're quite right of course.  I was hoping to move that conditional in code into the query itself, but this is not supported by the JPQL BNF.

Comment: I will offer in my feeble defense that the following kind of SQL (not JPQL) is often seen in generated scenarios: `SELECT x FROM y WHERE 1 = 1;` (i.e. whatever is assembling the `WHERE` clause sometimes makes sure that `1 = 1` is in the `WHERE` clause so dynamic assembly does not have to do the sort of if/then logic you're talking about).  Having said that, I don't think I can get away with this in JPQL.  Thanks.