# Dealing with empty or null collection parameter in JPA

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, jpql

Inside `org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.@Query` annotation I check if field in a collection and possibly ignore collection if it is empty:

```
@Query(""select e from #{#entityName} where e.type in :lst or 0 = :lstSize")
List<Entity> findByLst(@Param("lst") List<XEnum> lst, @Param("lstSize") int lstSize);
```

I call code as:

```
List<XEnum> lst = ...;
int lstSize = (lst == null) ? 0 : lst.size();
findByLst(lst, lstSize);
```

For Oracle DB in case of `lst = null` Hibernate logged:

```
DEBUG [nio-8443-exec-4] org.hibernate.SQL
entity0_.type in (?) or 0=?
TRACE [nio-8443-exec-4] org.hibernate.type.EnumType
Binding null to parameter: [1]
TRACE [nio-8443-exec-4] org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder
binding parameter [2] as [INTEGER] - [0]
```

For case of `lst = new LinkedList<>()` Hibernate logged:

```
DEBUG [nio-8443-exec-5] org.hibernate.SQL
entity0_.type in ( ) or 0=?
TRACE [nio-8443-exec-5] org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder
binding parameter [1] as [INTEGER] - [0]
ERROR [nio-8443-exec-5] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper
ORA-00936: missing expression
```

and it is syntactically invalid in SQL*PLUS also:

```
select 1 from dual where 1 in ();
```

Can I omit `lstSize` and still check if collection is not provided - return all elements?

How can I deal with empty list and Oracle `()` syntax error?

Actually I have large JPQL expression that handle several cases of empty arguments with single call. My goal to keep simple method instead of writing several specialized methods, using `if/else` or Critetia builder...

For example ignoring empty parameters can be archived with:

```
 ... and (e.field = :fieldVal or :fieldVal is null)
```

**UPDATE** Relevant resources:

- [Passing empty list as parameter to JPA query throws error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2488930/passing-empty-list-as-parameter-to-jpa-query-throws-error)
- https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8091 (Hibernate produces SQL - "in ()" - which is invalid in at least Oracle, MySQL and Postgres)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2488930/passing-empty-list-as-parameter-to-jpa-query-throws-error

Answer (score 0):

[Criteria API](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjitv.html) is for a rescue.

You are building SQL queries dynamically (and there is a possibility to work *type safe* when you generate special classes from entities by build tool plugin).

Spring Data provides convenience in a form of `org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.Specification` + `org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaSpecificationExecutor`, so querying might look like:

```
Specification<Book> spec = (Root<Book> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder builder) -> {
    ...
    if (CollectinUtils.isNotEmpty(ids)) {
        root.get("id").in(ids);
    }
}
List<Book> booksByIds = repository.findAll(spec);
```

Hibernate Criteria API supports `null` in `AND` or `OR` ignoring that expression making it convenient to omit empty check if you put `IN` operator builder in utility function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JPA  [NotEmpty or IsNotEmpty](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repository-query-keywords)

Example Code

Entity

```
public class products{
  ....fields

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "productId")
  @JsonIgnore
  private List<Rating> ratingList;

  .....geter/setter
}


public class Rating{
  ....fields
 
 @JoinColumn(name = "product_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
 @ManyToOne
 @JsonIgnore
 private Products productId;

  .....geter/setter

}
```

Repository

```
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Products, Integer>{
   public Page<Products> findByRatingListNotEmpty(Pageable pg);
}
```

Comment: I believe you made typo in the method: omitted `ratingList`, note that the name of methos is `findByRatingList`...