# Problem with sql - java.sql.SQLException: Operand should contain 1 column(s) (once

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I'm using Spring Data for select operation on MySql DataBase.

I'm trying to get all Institutions by `listOfWhomHelp`.
I expected all records(`institutions`) which contain `listOfWhomHelp`, but   if I choose more than one element in `listOfWhomHelp` it throws me:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Operand should contain 1 column(s)
com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:963)
```

**Repository method**

```
List<Institution> findAllByWhomHelp(List<InstitutionListOfWhomHelp> institutionListOfWhomHelp);
```

**Service method**

```
public List<Institution> findInstitutions(Institution institution) throws NullPointerException {

    if(institution.getInstitutionLocations().isEmpty()){
        return institutionRepository.findAllByWhomHelp(institution.getWhomHelp());
    }
}
```

There is also list of `InstitutionLocation`, but I always choose on of them

**Institution**

```
@NotEmpty
@ManyToMany
private List<InstitutionListOfWhomHelp> whomHelp;
```

**InstitutionListOfWhomHelp**

```
@NotBlank
private String whomHelp;

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "whomHelp")
private List<Institution> institution;
```

Comment: don't you think it should use `!` like 
` if(! institution.getWhomHelp().isEmpty()){ 
            return institutionRepository.findAllByWhomHelp(institution.getWhomHelp());
        }`

Comment: you can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2488930/passing-empty-list-as-parameter-to-jpa-query-throws-error) or [here](https://rzymek.github.io/post/jpa-empty-in/).

Comment: But the problem is that ``institution.getWhomHelp()`` isn't empty - i checked this before.This is the way when list ``institution.getInstitutionLocations()`` is empty and ``whomHelp`` isn't. 
I've also take care of NullPointerException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try like bottom

```
instituonRepository.findAllByWhomHelpIn
```

Thanks