# Null and Empty Check for a IN Clause parameter for Spring data jpa @query?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, sql-server-2012, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

My Spring data JPA code to get the data from db based on some search criteria is not working. My DB is SQL Server 2012, same query seem to work with MYSQL DB.

Code Example :

```
@Query(value = "select * from entity e where e.emp_id=:#{#mySearchCriteria.empId} and ((:#{#mySearchCriteria.deptIds} is null or :#{#mySearchCriteria.deptIds} ='') or e.dept_id in (:#{#mySearchCriteria.deptIds})) ", nativeQuery = true)
public List<Entity> search(@Param("mySearchCriteria") MySearchCriteria mySearchCriteria);
```

if list mySearchCriteria.deptIds  has more than one value- it's not working(it's actually translating it to wrong query. Any lead? Thanks in advance.

**Note:  data type for deptIds is List of Integer**

Comment: what error message it produces? what is the type of mySearchCriteria.deptIds field?

Comment: @Woworks It's actually List of Integers, error log says- the result is not translating to boolean

Comment: exact error message in log  is : "message":"An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ','."

Answer (score 1):

Its complaining because values of `{#mySearchCriteria.deptIds}` is comma separated list e.g. `'Value1', 'Value2'` so the query gets translated as `('Value1', 'Value2' is null)` which causes this error.

Need to verify if list is empty or not and then change the query with IN clause and one without IN clause.

Comment: Can't be done with one query? Also mysql handled if list is null or empty by itself, is it specific to SQL Server 2012  that it's not handling?

Comment: nope not specific to sql server. refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2488930/passing-empty-list-as-parameter-to-jpa-query-throws-error

Comment: ,My Question is that,  when I connect to MySql DB with same code-base (without null check for list object) and different mysql connector, it works( I mean if the list is null, it does not add it to query), however if I change the dialact, connector and db to MSSQL server ,  it add it to the query and my query result empty result set.

Comment: I didn't understand.. i thought you get an error message as `An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ','`. so you mean same query works differently with MySQL and MsSQL?

Comment: Yes you're right. My application works fine with mysql, i am migrating to sql server, so now some of the queries are failing

Answer (score 0):

Surround the list by parentheses. This works for me.

```
(:#{#mySearchCriteria.deptIds}) is null
```